# Calling webApi from windows store App

Tags: c#

I have a solution containing three projects. One windows store app, one PCL and one unit-test.

Im trying to call a web-api that I have running on localhost.

In the test-project it works fine but when I try to run the same code from the PCL I get the following exception:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:12345
```

I aslo tried to add a console-app and run the sam code and it worked. The must be something Im missing regarding the windows store app.

Here is the code I use to call the API:

```
 public async void CallMyApi()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:12345/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/user/16").Result;
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                       //success
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    //fail
                }
            }
        }
```

Have anyone had similar problems and know of a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: You're sure your service is running? Any particular reason why you use `GetAsync().Result` instead of `await GetAsync()`? Note that `async` methods should return `Task`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes im positive the servide is running. I also tried changing GetAsync().Result to Await GetAsync(). Same result. I do not understan how it can work in a console-app or as a unit-test...

Comment: I might also add that when I run the WebApi on localhost at the same time as the windows store App (they are in separate solutions) the method in the webApi never gets hit...

Comment: Another interesting thing is that this problem only occurs when i run the webApi on local host. WHen i put it online it works as expected..